# SVG animation hover animation not working on Wordpress

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I got this SVG that i animated on hover:

[This svg](http://classmate.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Markedsfoering.svg)

But when I'm using it on my site, it doesn't animate? Do anyone got any suggestions why this is?

The page that it's not working on is [this](http://classmate.dk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including it via an `<img>` tag and SVG when displayed as an image is not interactive. You'd need to include it via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag instead.